# \newcommand with easily configurable optional parameters

Tags: macros, formatting, itemize, bullets

Consider I have the following commands:

```latex
\newcommand{\ListStartSimple}{\begin{itemize}[label={}, leftmargin=0.15in]}
\newcommand{\ListStartLineSimple}{\begin{itemize}[label={}, leftmargin=0.38in]}

\newcommand{\ListStartBullet}{\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, leftmargin=0.15in]}
\newcommand{\ListStartLineBullet}{\begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet, leftmargin=0.38in]}

\newcommand{\ListStartBulletTiny}{\begin{itemize}[label=\tiny\textbullet, leftmargin=0.15in]}
\newcommand{\ListStartLineBulletTiny}{\begin{itemize}[label=\tiny\textbullet, leftmargin=0.38in]}

\newcommand{\ListStartDash}{\begin{itemize}[label=\textendash, leftmargin=0.15in]}
\newcommand{\ListStartLineDash}{\begin{itemize}[label=\textendash, leftmargin=0.38in]}

\newcommand{\ListEnd}[1][-5]{\end{itemize}\vspace{#1pt}}
```

So in my Tex file, I can easily begin a list with my configurations.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\ListStartSimple \item This is a list \ListEnd
\ListStartLineSimple \item This is a list \ListEnd
\ListStartBullet \item This is a list \ListEnd
\ListStartLineBullet \item This is a list \ListEnd
\ListStartBulletTiny \item This is a list \ListEnd
\ListStartLineBulletTiny \item This is a list \ListEnd
\ListStartDash \item This is a list \ListEnd
\ListStartLineDash \item This is a list \ListEnd

\end{document}
```

#### Which gives me:

[image]

#### What do I need?

As you can see, these commands are redundant and could be easily summarized into one command. Instead of having different `\newcommand`s, I prefer to have **only one command with `hasmargin, label, labelsize` parameters**. So I can generate the exact above image with something similar to this:

```latex
\List \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[withmargin] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[bullet] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[withmargin,bullet] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[bullet,tiny] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[hasmargin,bullet,tiny] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[dash] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[hasmargin,dash] \item This is a list \ListEnd
```

Comment: your example doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package xkeyval provides an interface for accepting keys:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% BEGIN Source:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598048/newcommand-with-easily-configurable-optional-parameters
\makeatletter
\def\ListLabelSize{}
\def\ListLabel{}
\newlength\ListLeftmargin
\def\ListItemSep{}
\def\ListDefaults{}

\define@key{List}{simple}[]{
    \def\ListLabel{}
}

\define@key{List}{bullet}[]{
    \def\ListLabel{\textbullet}
}

\define@key{List}{dash}[]{
    \def\ListLabel{\textendash}
}

\define@key{List}{tiny}[]{
    \def\ListLabelSize{\tiny}
}

\define@key{List}{normalsize}[]{
    \def\ListLabelSize{\normalsize}
}

\define@key{List}{large}[]{
    \def\ListLabelSize{\large}
}

\define@key{List}{withmargin}[]{
    \setlength\ListLeftmargin{0.38in}
}

\define@key{List}{hasmargin}[]{
    \setlength\ListLeftmargin{0.38in}
}

\define@key{List}{nomargin}[]{
    \setlength\ListLeftmargin{0.15in}
}

\newcommand\SetListDefaults[1]{
    \def\ListDefaults{simple,nomargin,normalsize,#1}
}

\newcommand\ListStart[1][]{
    \def\@applyList##1{
        \setkeys*{List}{##1}
    }
    \expandafter\@applyList\expandafter{\ListDefaults,#1}
    \def\createbeginitemize##1{
        \begin{itemize}[
            label={\ListLabelSize\ListLabel},
            leftmargin={\ListLeftmargin},
            ##1
        ]
    }
    % XKV@rm contains the keys we didn't define ourselves, we pass
    % them to itemize
    \expandafter\createbeginitemize\expandafter{\XKV@rm}
}

\newcommand\ListEnd[1][0]{
    \end{itemize}\vspace{#1pt}
}
\makeatother
% END Source

\SetListDefaults{topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt}

\newenvironment{List}[1][]{
    \ListStart[#1]
}{
    \ListEnd[]
}

\begin{document}

\List \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[withmargin] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[bullet] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[withmargin,bullet] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[bullet,tiny] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[hasmargin,bullet,tiny] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[dash] \item This is a list \ListEnd
\List[hasmargin,dash] \item This is a list \ListEnd

\begin{List}[bullet,large]
    \item This is a list
    \item With items
\end{List}

\end{document}
```

[image: Lissts as in OP]

I've made it so that keys you didn't define yourself are passed to `\begin{itemize}[]`. This way you can for example use `topsep=0pt` without needing to define a key for it first. Also, note how I made a handy `\SetListDefaults`. You can change those defaults at any time, also within your document. Is handy to avoid repetition.

Hope you're happy with it :)

Has this answered helped you?

**EDIT:**

To see how the `\define@key` and such works, the best place is the `xkeyval` package documentation: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval

There are more things to learn from in the code. For example the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. The '@' signs in command names are a sort of child lock: normally, you can't use an '@' sign a command. But you can if you use `\makeatletter`. Hence you can make 'internal' commands which users of your package can't accidentally use instead of the real commands.

The `\def` works in much the same way as a `\newcommand`, it's a bit more light-weight. (view [TeXbyTopic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf), page 109). You see how I use them to capture the values within them. Also a length is used (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Length_manipulation).

There are a couple more things, like when defining macros within macros, you use `##1` for its argument, because `#1` is reserved for the enclosing macro.

Finally, why I sometimes define these tiny helper macros: this is because I want to 'paste in' the contents of what I have captured. If I pass `\ListDefaults` alongside the other keys, LaTeX will think `\ListDefaults` is just a key like `bullet` for example. And of course, it cannot find that key. We need to 'expand' it ourselves: put the contents of `\ListDefaults` in directly.

To solve this, I define a macro which can paste the contents at the right spot. Next, I use `\expandafter`'s, which 'expand' 'after'. See the different steps of expanding (with `(~0)` I indicate where LaTeX is executing, and with `(~1)` where it will resume after executing):

```
(~0)\expandafter(~1)\createbeginitemize\expandafter{\XKV@rm}
(~1)\createbeginitemize(~0)\expandafter{\XKV@rm}
(~1)\createbeginitemize{(~0)\XKV@rm}
(~1)\createbeginitemize{bullet,large}
(~0)\createbeginitemize{bullet,large}
```

You see the `\expandafter`'s allow you to 'hop' over a command or a brace. And now, it won't read `\ListDefaults`, but `bullet,large` properly.

There is so much to tell, hope I gave you a good quickstart here, and keep exploring to become an expert!

Comment: Yeah, but a little difficult to understand the commands themselves. Please link any useful datasheets or documents so I can have a better understanding of this code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Tabaraei Ah, a curious mind! I've added a whole bunch of information. Hope you like it!

Comment: Haha, thank you very much!